# reading multiple matches into arrays with bash

Tags: arrays, bash, awk

The utility 'sas2ircu' can output multiple lines for every hard drive attached to the host. A sample of the output for a single drive looks like this:

```
  Enclosure #                             : 5
  Slot #                                  : 20
  SAS Address                             : 5003048-0-185f-b21c
  State                                   : Ready (RDY)
```

I have a bash script that executes the sas2ircu command and does the following with the output:

1. identifies a drive by the RDY string
2. reads the numerical value of the enclosure (ie, 5) into an array 'enc'
3. reads the numerical value of the slot (ie, 20) into another array 'slot'

The code I have serves its purpose, but I'm trying to figure out if I can combine it into a single line and run the sas2ircu command once instead of twice.

```
mapfile -t enc < <(/root/sas2ircu 0 display|grep -B3 RDY|awk '/Enclosure/{print $NF}')
mapfile -t slot < <(/root/sas2ircu 0 display|grep -B2 RDY|awk '/Slot/{print $NF}')
```

I've done a bunch of reading on awk but I'm still quite novice with it and haven't come up with anything better than what I have. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to eliminate the `grep` and combine the `awk` scripts into a single `awk` script; the general idea is to capture the enclosure and slot data and then if/when we see `State/RDY` we print the enclosure and slot to stdout:

```
awk '/Enclosure/{enclosure=$NF}/Slot/{slot=$NF}/State.*(RDY)/{print enclosure,slot}'
```

I don't have `sas2ircu` so I'll simulate some data (based on OP's sample):

```
$ cat raw.dat
  Enclosure #                             : 5
  Slot #                                  : 20
  SAS Address                             : 5003048-0-185f-b21c
  State                                   : Ready (RDY)

  Enclosure #                             : 7
  Slot #                                  : 12
  SAS Address                             : 5003048-0-185f-b21c
  State                                   : Ready (RDY)

  Enclosure #                             : 9
  Slot #                                  : 23
  SAS Address                             : 5003048-0-185f-b21c
  State                                   : Off (OFF)
```

Simulating thw `sas2ircu` call:

```
$ cat raw.dat | awk '/Enclosure/{enclosure=$NF}/Slot/{slot=$NF}/State.*(RDY)/{print enclosure,slot}'
5 20
7 12
```

The harder part is going to be reading these into 2 separate arrays and I'm not aware of an easy way to do this with a single command (eg, `mapfile` doesn't provide a way to split an input file across 2 arrays).

One idea using a `bash/while` loop:

```
unset enc slot

while read -r e s
do
    enc+=( ${e} )
    slot+=( ${s} )
done < <(cat raw.dat | awk '/Enclosure/{enclosure=$NF}/Slot/{slot=$NF}/State.*(RDY)/{print enclosure,slot}')
```

This generates:

```
$ typeset -p enc slot
declare -a enc=([0]="5" [1]="7")
declare -a slot=([0]="20" [1]="12")
```